# Lunch Remote Application C++ MFC

Tags: mfc

I want to launch a "test.bat" command file on a disk that's on a remote machine.

I created a connection on the shared space with a disk logic (L:) with no problems, but when I want to launch it with `CreateProcess(..)` there's a mistake.

The test file, bat just contains "`dir`".

My environment is Visual Studio 2019 CPP MFC. The logical disk is mounted with:

```
{ .... dwRetVal = WNetAddConnection2 ((CString)Pass_buffer_Root, (CString)Account_buffer_Root, CONNECT_TEMPORARY); ... }
```

And for the launch:

```
{ ... STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) }; info.cb = sizeof(info); PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo; ZeroMemory(&processInfo, sizeof(processInfo)); BOOL Result = CreateProcess(NULL, File.GetBuffer(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo); ... }
```

The result is zero, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw):

> To run a batch file, you must start the command interpreter; set *lpApplicationName* to cmd.exe and set *lpCommandLine* to the following arguments: /c plus the name of the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem of launching a command file purpose this file is in a shared resource and the command "dir" is not recognized on the remote machine. Even if I give it the complete path "c:windows-cmd.exe /c "